# vXML number readback error

Tags: vxml

**ANSWER : `<say-as interpret-as="number_digit">`**
Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd450828(v=office.13).aspx

I have a simple field (shown below) to collect the callers 9 digit account number.

It works correctly in that it collects the number, and it reads it back. My problem is that when it reads back the number, it considers it a whole number. For example if they enter 111111111 it reads it as 111,111,111 (one hundred and eleven million..ect.)

Obviously I would like it to read back one digit at a time, example:

"You entered 1, 2, 3, ect. "

Here is my simple code:

```
<field name="accountnumber" type="digits?minlength=9;maxlength=9">            
    <prompt>
What is your 9 digit account number
</prompt>         
    <filled>            
                <prompt>  You said <value expr="accountnumber"/> </prompt>
    </filled>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your `<value>` inside a `<say-as>` tag:

```
<say-as interpret-as="digits">
  <value expr="accountnumber"/>
</say-as>
```

The `interpret-as` attribute may somewhat depend on what your VXML engine supports. For example, Voxeo uses "digits", Microsoft seems to use "number:digit", and the SSML 1.0 spec says "characters". Some also use the attribute `type` instead of `interpret-as`.

Comment: I tried all three, none of them produced the results I was hoping for. I did know of the say-as for digits, but not the other two. I need to find a way to figure out which engine this server is using I suppose.

Comment: Close enough for an answer. I found out that the answer for my version is
<say-as interpret-as="number_digit"> Appears to be SSML 2.0